# specify Popup size relatively in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

in WPF, I have the following `Popup` numpad. It shows up at the center of the `mainDisplay` with fixed size.

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=mainDisplay}" Placement="Center" Name="numpadPop">
    <Frame Width="300" Height="300" Name="numpadFrame">
    </Frame>
</Popup>
```

Is there a way to specify its size relatively, say 80% the height of the `mainDisplay`? Thanks!

---

EDIT: I got errors in XAML in trying Kenny's solution. Below is my App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="myappname.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myappname"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:MySizeConverter x:Key="sizeConverter"/>    
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

errors: (I did define the class MySizeConverter)

```
Error   1   The property "Resources" can only be set once.
Error   2   The namespace prefix "local" is not defined.
Error   14  The name "MySizeConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:myappname".
Error   6   The "Key" attribute can only be used on an element that is contained in "IDictionary".
```

---

UPDATE:
Originally `MySizeConverter` wasn't `public`, which seemed to be the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the height of the frame to the height of `mainDisplay`, you also need specify a [converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) which accepts the height of `mainDisplay` and returns the height of the frame.

```
<Frame Height="{Binding ElementName=mainDisplay, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource sizeConverter}}" Width="{Binding ElementName=mainDisplay, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource sizeConverter}}" Name="numpadFrame">
</Frame>
```

The converter:

```
public class sizeConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return 0.8 * (double)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add it to App's resource dictionary (App.xaml), so you can reference it with `{StaticResource key}`.

```
<Application x:Class="yournamespace.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yournamespace"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:sizeConverter x:Key="sizeConverter" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Read the [tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) if you have problem in compiling the code and XAML.

Comment: i got an error on this line `<local:sizeConverter x:Key="sizeConverter" />`. The error is `The "Key" attribute can only be used on an element that is contained in "IDictionary".` any idea why? thanks again for the help!

Comment: where do you put this line? it has to be in resource dictionary like `<Application.Resources></Application.Resources>`

Comment: Make sure the namespace of the class `MySizeConverter` is `myappname`, not `myappname.something`.

Comment: yes, it is just `myappname`. thanks for your help, and I'll post back when I find the errors.